# How can I write UTF-8 files using JavaScript for Mac Automation?

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, javascript-automation

**In short - what is the JavaScript for Mac Automation equivalent of AppleScript's `as «class utf8»` ?**

I have a unicode string that I'm trying to write to a text file using JavaScript for Mac Automation.

When writing the string to the file, any unicode characters present become question marks in the file (ASCII char `3F`).

If this was an AppleScript script instead of a JavaScript one, I could have solved this by adding the `as «class utf8»` raw statement as explained on Takashi Yoshida's Blog (https://takashiyoshida.org/blog/applescript-write-text-as-utf8-string-to-file/).

The script, however, is already written in JavaScript so I'm looking for the JavaScript equivalent to this AppleScript statement. Apple's page about raw statements addresses only AppleScript (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_raw_data.html).

To write the file, I am using Apple's own `writeTextToFile` JavaScript function example (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReadandWriteFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH58-SW1). I added an `as` argument to the following call, according to the StandardAdditions dictionary:

```
// Write the new content to the file
app.write(text, { to: openedFile, startingAt: app.getEof(openedFile), as: "utf8" })
```

And tried all of the following strings (as written and also in lowercase form):

- Unicode text
- Unicode
- Class utf8
- «class utf8»
- utf8
- text
- utf8 text

Apart for "text" (which resulted in the same question marks situation), using all of the above strings yielded a zero-bytes file.

I understand I might be wading into uncharted waters here, but if anyone reading this has dealt with this before and is willing to provide some pointers, I will be quite grateful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to ensure your file gets written with UTF8 encoding, use NSString's `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error` function, like so:

```
fileStr = $.NSString.alloc.initWithUTF8String( 'your string here' )
fileStr.writeToFileAtomicallyEncodingError( filePath, true, $.NSUTF8StringEncoding, $() )
```

You would think that writing an NSString object initialized from a UTF8 string would get written out as UTF8 but I've found from experience that `writeToFile:atomically` does not honor the encoding of the string being written out. `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error` explicitly specifies which encoding to use. On top of that, `writeToFile:atomically` has been deprecated by Apple since OS X 10.4.

Answer (score 1):

[@PatrickWayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3505188/patrick-wynne) has [the correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44278929/915019).

I already had this function in my lib, so I thought I'd share it.
It uses the same key commands.

```js
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
function writeFile(pPathStr, pOutputStr) {  //  @File @Write @ObjC
  /*  VER: 2.0  2017-03-18  
---------------------------------------------------------------
  PARAMETERS:
    pPathStr    | string  | Path of file to write.  May use tilde (~)
    pOutputStr  |  string  |  String to be output to file.
  */
  
  //--- CONVERT TO NS STRING ---
  var nsStr       = $.NSString.alloc.initWithUTF8String(pOutputStr)
  
  //--- EXPAND TILDE AND CONVERT TO NS PATH ---
  var nsPath      = $(pPathStr).stringByStandardizingPath
  
  //--- WRITE TO FILE ---
  //      Returns true IF successful, ELSE false
  var successBool  = nsStr.writeToFileAtomicallyEncodingError(nsPath, false, $.NSUTF8StringEncoding, null)
  
  if (!successBool) {
    throw new Error("function writeFile ERROR:\nWrite to File FAILED for:\n" + pPathStr)
  }
  
  return successBool
  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

While I was unable to find a way to do it with JavaScript only, I ended up utilizing the Objective-C Bridge to accomplish UTF-8 file write-out.

Here is the code that I used. This is JavaScript code that invokes the Objective-C NSString class, and it replaces the `writeTextToFile` function that I mentioned above altogether:

```
objCText = $.NSString.alloc.initWithUTF8String(text);
objCText.writeToFileAtomically(filePathString, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

JXA can't do symbol types (type and enumerator names) right, and it can't do raw four-char codes at all. Either stick to AppleScript, which is the only officially supported option that speaks Apple events right, or use the Cocoa bridge to write a NSString to file in NSUTF8StringEncoding, c.f. Patrick's solution.