# How do I write a LZ compressed string to text file using JXA?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, lzo, javascript-automation

I am trying to write a JXA script in Apple Script Editor, that compresses a string using the LZ algorithm and writes it to a text (JSON) file:

```
var story = "Once upon a time in Silicon Valley..."
var storyC = LZString.compress(story)
var data_to_write = "{\x22test\x22\x20:\x20\x22"+storyC+"\x22}"
app.displayAlert(data_to_write)
var desktopString = app.pathTo("desktop").toString()
var file = `${desktopString}/test.json`
writeTextToFile(data_to_write, file, true)
```

Everything works, except that the LZ compressed string is just transformed to a set of "?" by the time it reaches the output file, *test.json*.

It should look like:

```
{"test" : "㲃냆੠Њޱᐈ攀렒삶퓲ٔ쀛䳂䨀푖㢈Ӱນꀀ"}
```

Instead it looks like:

```
{"test" : "????????????????????"}
```

I have a feeling the conversion is happening in the *app.write* command used by the *writeTextToFile()* function (which I pulled from an example in [Apple's Mac Automation Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReadandWriteFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH58-SW1)):

```
var app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true

function writeTextToFile(text, file, overwriteExistingContent) {
    try {

        // Convert the file to a string
        var fileString = file.toString()

        // Open the file for writing
        var openedFile = app.openForAccess(Path(fileString), { writePermission: true })

        // Clear the file if content should be overwritten
        if (overwriteExistingContent) {
            app.setEof(openedFile, { to: 0 })
        }

        // Write the new content to the file
        app.write(text, { to: openedFile, startingAt: app.getEof(openedFile) })

        // Close the file
        app.closeAccess(openedFile)

        // Return a boolean indicating that writing was successful
        return true
    }
    catch(error) {

        try {
            // Close the file
            app.closeAccess(file)
        }
        catch(error) {
            // Report the error is closing failed
            console.log(`Couldn't close file: ${error}`)
        }

        // Return a boolean indicating that writing was successful
        return false
    }
}
```

Is there a substitute command for *app.write* that maintains the LZ compressed string / a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

In addition, I am using the *readFile()* function (also from the [Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReadandWriteFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH58-SW1)) to load the LZ string back into the script:

```
function readFile(file) {
    // Convert the file to a string
    var fileString = file.toString()

    // Read the file and return its contents
    return app.read(Path(fileString))
}
```

But rather than returning:

```
{"test" : "㲃냆੠Њޱᐈ攀렒삶퓲ٔ쀛䳂䨀푖㢈Ӱນꀀ"}
```

It is returning:

```
"{\"test\" : \"„≤ÉÎÉÜ‡©†–äÓÄéﬁ±·êàÊîÄÎ†íÏÇ∂Ìì≤ŸîÏÄõ‰≥Ç‰®ÄÌëñ„¢à”∞‡∫ôÍÄÄ\"}"
```

Does anybody know a fix for this too?

I know that it is possible to [use Cocoa in JXA scripts](https://tylergaw.com/articles/building-osx-apps-with-js/), so maybe the solution lies therein?

I am just getting to grips with JavaScript so I'll admit trying to grasp Objective-C or Swift is way beyond me right now.

I look forward to any solutions and/or pointers that you might be able to provide me.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After some further Googl'ing, I came across these two posts:

- [How can I write UTF-8 files using JavaScript for Mac Automation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44293869/11616368)
- [read file as class utf8](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/issues/25#issuecomment-271204038)

I have thus altered my script accordingly.

*writeTextToFile()* now looks like:

```
function writeTextToFile(text, file) {
  // source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44293869/11616368
  var nsStr       = $.NSString.alloc.initWithUTF8String(text)
  var nsPath      = $(file).stringByStandardizingPath
  var successBool  = nsStr.writeToFileAtomicallyEncodingError(nsPath, false, $.NSUTF8StringEncoding, null)
  if (!successBool) {
    throw new Error("function writeFile ERROR:\nWrite to File FAILED for:\n" + file)
  }
  return successBool  
};
```

While *readFile()* looks like:

```
ObjC.import('Foundation')
const readFile = function (path, encoding) {
  // source: https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/issues/25#issuecomment-271204038
    pathString = path.toString()
    !encoding && (encoding = $.NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    const fm = $.NSFileManager.defaultManager
    const data = fm.contentsAtPath(pathString)
    const str = $.NSString.alloc.initWithDataEncoding(data, encoding)
    return ObjC.unwrap(str)
};
```

Both use Objective-C to overcome *app.write* and *app.read*'s inability to handle UTF-8.